# loop through dataframe column and plot all variable?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a list of 35 variable and want to plot all the variable histogram to see the type of distribution.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 6)
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        for column in X.columns:
            axs[i,j] = sns.distplot(X[column], hist=True, kde=True, 
               bins=int(180/5), color = 'darkblue', 
               hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'},
               kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
            axs[i,j].set_title(column)
```

Currently it is printing only the last 35th variable.

Comment: Do u want to plot all the variable in 36 plots?

Comment: yes all the 36 variables plot

Answer (score 0):

This small change should do the trick:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6, 6)
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if (i*6) + j > 33:
            break
        curr_column = X.columns[(i*6) + j]
        sns.distplot(X[curr_column], hist=True, kde=True,
                     ax=axs[i,j], 
                     bins=int(180/5), color = 'darkblue', 
                     hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'},
                     kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
        axs[i,j].set_title(curr_column)
```

Comment: i am getting this error
index 34 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 34

Comment: That sounds like you don't have 36 columns. check with `X.shape`. Is it possible one of the variables you want to plot is set as the index of the dataframe?

Comment: oh sorry its 34

Comment: @DineshKumar: Edited the code such that it stops plotting after 34 column (i.e. index 33):

Comment: It is still plotting the last column

Comment: @DineshKumar: True, for Seaborn, you need to specify the subplot as an argument. Made another edit.

Comment: Happy to help. Upvote / marking the correct answer would be appreciated :)